# std::cin >> *aa results in a bus error

Tags: c++, pointers, char, const-char, bus-error

I have this a class called PPString:

#### PPString.h

```
#ifndef __CPP_PPString
#define __CPP_PPString

#include "PPObject.h"

class PPString : public PPObject {
    char *stringValue[];
public:
    char *pointerToCharString();
    void setCharString(char *charString[]);
    void setCharString(const char charString[]);
};

#endif
```

#### PPString.cpp

```
#include "PPString.h"

char *PPString::pointerToCharString() {
    return *stringValue;
}

void PPString::setCharString(char *charString[]) {
    *stringValue = *charString;
}

void PPString::setCharString(const char charString[]) {
    *stringValue = (char *)charString;
}
```

I'm trying to set the `stringValue` using `std::cin`:

#### main.cpp

```
PPString myString;
myString.setCharString("LOLZ");
std::cout << myString.pointerToCharString() << std::endl;

char *aa[1000];
std::cin >> *aa;
myString.setCharString(aa);
std::cout << myString.pointerToCharString() << std::endl;
```

The first one, which uses a `const char` works, but the second one, with a `char` doesn't, and I get this output:

#### copy and paste from STDOUT

```
LOLZ
im entering a string now...
Bus error
```

where the second line is what I entered, followed by pressing the `return` key.

Can anyone help me fixing this? Thanks...

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive title. It lets one know what your question is about without having to read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setCharString with the `char *s[]` signature is dereferencing the first element of an array of pointers to `char*`.  It has not been allocated.  If you change the declaration of `aa` to `char aa[1000];`, it will probably run.

There are some other issues too (also pointed out by others).   The assignment to the variable `stringValue` is also dereferencing memory that does not appear to have been allocated.  It's hard to say what the usage is, but it should maybe not have the `[]` declaration.  In addition, the assignment is storing a pointer to stack memory, which will likely not be valid after another function call.

Comment: ...until someone enters 1005 characters.

Comment: @Alex: I changed it to `char aa`, `std::cin >> &aa` and `myString.setCharString(&aa)` and removed the asterisks from the function declecations. It works now without a limit of characters.

Answer (score 1):

When you say:

```
char *aa[1000];
std::cin >> *aa;
```

*aa has no memory allocated to it. Same sort of problem here:

```
char *stringValue[];
```

And the name `__CPP_PPString` is reserved in C++, as are all names that contain a double underscore or begin with an underscore and an uppercase letter. You are not allowed to create them in your own code,

Answer (score 1):

`char *aa[1000];` is not what you think it is. It's an array of 1000 `char *`'s.

Use `std::string` instead. That way, you don't have to worry about someone entering more than 1000 characters and exploiting your program.

E.g.

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
```

Comment: The problem of this, is that soon I'll not link to the standard library anymore. The classes are actually in my own static library. Maybe I could use std::string as buffer for now. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Koning you are rewriting standard lib?

Comment: @Kugel, not really. I'm writing a program which links to my static-library to test it. That static-library indeed doesn't link to anything.

Answer (score 0):

What compiler are you using? Try using a different compiler or enabling all warnings for the one you're using, the compiler should be telling you the errors for this code, you don't need to find out at runtime.

For example, Comeau online will tell you:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 4: error: incomplete type is not allowed
      char *stringValue[];
            ^

"ComeauTest.c", line 23: warning: variable "aa" is used before its value is set
  std::cin >> *aa;
```